# Mongoose complains that an integer is a number not an integer

Tags: node.js, json, express, mongoose

I have some Mongoose code which fails running on NodeJS.

The relevant line is:

```
// get data from database
const existingUser = await User.findOne({ userId });
```

`userId` is a "number" type.

```
console.log(typeof userId); // -> number
console.log(userId);        // -> 1
```

This value is obtained from the body of a http request where the body is encoded as JSON.

Therefore I am not surprised to find that the type is "number" because all JSON numbers are the same (floating point, no integers) however I am surprised to find that this causes an error and Mongoose cannot convert the number to an integer type.

Here the request is received by a post endpoint defined in express.

```
app.post("/test", async (request, response) => {
    // get user id from body of request

    console.log(request.body); // -> { userId: 1 }

    const userId = request.body.userId;

    // ...
```

How can I fix this?

The exact error is:

```
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "1" (type number) at path "userId" for model "User"

reason: BSONError: input must be a 24 character hex string, 12 byte Uint8Array, or an integer
```

The relevant schema is:

```
const user = new mongoose.Schema({
  userId: {
    type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
  },
});
```

Comment: Can you post your Schema so I can explain what is happening? It may help with using mongoose in your project.

Comment: @jQueeny Sure - see appended update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you query a collection on a property that is of type `ObjectId` mongoose will internally cast your query parameter value to an `ObjectId` in order to do an equality check. This is very handy.

However, a great source of confusion is that an [`ObjectId`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/) such as `ObjectId("6578c06c3f3559a5e969fc88")` is made up of:

> A 4-byte timestamp, representing the ObjectId's creation, measured in seconds since the Unix epoch.
>
> [**6578c06c**] 3f3559a5e969fc88
>
> A 5-byte random value generated once per process. This random value is unique to the machine and process.
>
> 6578c06c [**3f3559a5e9**] 69fc88
>
> A 3-byte incrementing counter, initialized to a random value.
>
> 6578c06c3f3559a5e9 [**69fc88**]

In your case you have a number `userId` where

```js
request.body.userId === 1 // true
```

Mongoose sees that `User.userId` is an `ObjectId` and tries to cast your `userId` value to an `ObjectId` and can't so it throws a `Cast to ObjectId failed` error.

What you have done as a workaround is use the `mongoose.Types.ObjectId()` function to make a new `ObjectId` and then use that value to find a match. However that function not only takes a valid 24 character hexadecimal string but it also takes an integer.

You think you have converted your `userId` value to an `ObjectId` that will match a document but all you have done is create an `ObjectId` that is 1 second after the [Unix Epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) timestamp combined with the 5-byte random value and the 3-byte incrementing counter. To illustrate:

```js
console.log(new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(1));
// ObjectId('0000000108423469423cf5f1')

console.log(new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(1));
// ObjectId('0000000108423469423cf5f5')

console.log(new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(1));
// ObjectId('0000000108423469423cf5f9')
```

Your value of 1 has created the `00000001` part of the new `ObjectId`. You can run it a million times and you will always get the same `00000001`.

I am fairly certain you won't have any documents that were created at 00:00:01 UTC on 1 January 1970 so while your query won't error it won't find any documents.

All you need to do is allow your front-end to send a valid string form of an `ObjectId` such as `{ userId : "6578c06c3f3559a5e969fc88" }` and mongoose will do the rest.

Comment: This is a great answer, thanks. To clarify a few things. I am able to find the document again, because I use the same "userId==1" when creating and querying for it. But this makes a lot of sense and I agree knowing this what I am doing is clearly not sensible.

Comment: Actually, I should add, what I was doing here was really a hack for testing purposes. The "real" way this should be done would obviously be to create a document to represent the user, and to return the document id back via the same api so that I then do operate using a 24 character hex string.

Comment: Ahh, I see what you're doing. Yes, you are correct that the document id should be sent back and forth as part of the request. The `_id` field or in your case `userId` is the resource identifier and mongoose has been designed to expect that so has helpful implicit casting as it's a common process to find a resource it's identifier. Good luck with your project @FreelanceConsultant.

Comment: Actually, one question it sounds like you might know the answer to - MongoDB automatically generates the names of the document id: The name is "_id". Is there a way for me to interact with that as if the name were "userId" ?

Comment: Yes each document has an `_id` field as standard. Drivers will set the `_id` value before writing it to the database but if it's omitted mongodb will do it anyway as an `ObjectId`. You could use [virtuals](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/virtuals.html) so that when you query `userId` it actually retrieves `_id` @FreelanceConsultant

Answer (score 0):

For some reason it requires an explicit cast, or creation of an `ObjectId` type:

```
const existingUser = await User.findOne({
  userId: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId),
});
```

Answer (score -1):

As per your schema, you have defined userId as objectId.
You should always validate the mongoose ObjectId whether its valid or not using follwing code .

```
mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(req.body.userId.toString()
```

And to convert string into mongoose objectId

```
   new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.userId)
```

Comment: This is true but the documentation specifies that it should also accept an integer.